# How to disable Word Wrap in VS Code with Python extension?

Tags: python, formatting, vscode-extensions, word-wrap

When I write Python code in VS Code, all long lines get split in half after saving. I've already figured out that this is related to the Python extension.

- I've checked the user settings, where "WordWrap" is set to "Off." Is there anyone who can assist me with this? It's really annoying to write code like this.
- In the settings of the Python extension, I couldn't find anything that might be related to WordWrap or formatting.
- I had also found a few threads where a similar issue occurred. I tried the answers from these, unfortunately, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what your python formatting provider is in the settings.

```
"python.formatting.provider": "autopep8"
```

I only know a solution for `autopep8`.

Try changing `--max-line-length` to a larger value say 500.

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args" : [ "--max-line-length=500" ]
```

Hope this helps